# C# solution integration-Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am new to Sharepoint. I have an application created in C# Visual Studio 2010(web application).I have to show the contents and the solution inside of SharePoint so that the C# application could be used by its users without the need of Visual Studio having to be installed in each user's desktop.

I have to upload the C# solution to sharepoint portal server and then create a link in documents tab which will open this application. If that's the case,i am not sure how to do that any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the SharePoint Document library in Windows explorer mode copy your Solution. Please check the below link.
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-windows-explorer-view.html

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that any .NET app can run underneath SharePoint if the directory is excluded as a managed path.

Access to that app is easily done - either a simple redirect there or use the Page Viewer Web Part (an IFrame) to display the app "inside" SharePoint.

Easy - no code required.

Best Regards,

David M. Sterling
Sterling International Consulting Group